# Why doesn't the jQuery Font Resizer Resize?

Tags: jquery

I have added a font-resizer to this [page](http://energync.ehclients.com/news/article/usgbc-nc-the-nc-sustainable-energy-association-collaborate-on-legislative-a#) and it looks right, but the font does not resize.

The HTML I am targeting is .news p

The jQuery is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.news p').jfontsize();
</script>
```

However, when I click to enlarge the font, nothing happens. I would appreciate some guidance on how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Pointing to a page with errors won't help others in the future when this page will not exist... consider adding your actual markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'btnMinusClasseId' of undefined`

Looking at your html and at the docs for the plugin you didn't put the correct `ids` on your resize buttons. http://www.jfontsize.com/

Change:

```
<div id="font-resizer">
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-m2" href="#">A-</a>
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-d2" href="#">A</a>
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-p2" href="#">A+</a>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="font-resizer">
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-minus" href="#">A-</a>
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-default" href="#">A</a>
      <a class="jfontsize-button" id="jfontsize-plus" href="#">A+</a>
</div>
```

You might need to adjust your css if it was referencing the old `id`.

Comment: Hi Jack, I changed it as noted, but still no dice. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Whoops, they are supposed to be Ids. Updating my answer.